# Change record type in Apex using the info from client-side lightning

Tags: apex, record-type

Is it possible to change a record type in Apex using the info from client-side lightning?

Here is what I am trying to do.

In client-side:

```
const contact = {
    RecordType: {
        Id: idOfNewRecordType
    }
};

SRCommon.executeBackendRequest({
    component: this.component,
    apexMethodName: "c.changeContactData",
    params: {
        contact: contact
    },
    requestCallback: SRCommon.extractDataFromResponse({requestCallback: requestCallback})
});



executeBackendRequest: function(info) {
        const action = info.component.get(info.apexMethodName);
        action.setParams(info.params);
        action.setCallback(info.component, info.requestCallback);
        $A.getCallback(function(){$A.enqueueAction(action);})();
}
```

In Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void changeContactData(Contact contact) {
    update contact;
}
```

I actually checked that I am passing a correct id in `idOfNewRecordType`, but still the record type does not update. What am I missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know whether or not I come up with the best solution, but changing that

```
const contact = {
    RecordType: {
        Id: idOfNewRecordType
    }
};
```

to this

```
const contact = {
    RecordTypeId: idOfNewRecordType
};
```

did solve the issue.

Comment: Yep, that's the right solution. It's because `update` doesn't act on changes to any related objects, and the first version of your code is treating `RecordType` as a related object.